# Gatling - print current time before execution of scenario and pass that value to next scenario

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am executing 2 consecutive scenarios, I have a requirement where I need to record current time before start of 1st scenario and then pass that time value to next scenario. Can someone please suggest how this can be implemented. Please check below my code

```
def fileUpload() = foreach("${datasetIdList}","datasetId"){
  println("File Upload Start Time::::"+Calendar.getInstance().getTime+" for datasetId ::: ${datasetId}")
  exec(http("file upload").post("/datasets/${datasetId}/uploadFile")
    .formUpload("File","./src/test/resources/data/Scan_good.csv")
    .header("content-type","multipart/form-data")
    .check(status is 200).check(status.saveAs("uploadStatus")))
    .exec(session => {
      if(session("uploadStatus").as[Int] == 200)
        counter +=1
    session
  })
}

def getDataSetId() = foreach("${datasetIdList}","datasetId"){
    exec(http("get datasetId")
      .get("/datasets/${datasetId}")
      .header("content-type","application/json")
      .check(status is 200)
    )
```

I need to record upload start time for each iteration of datasetIdList and pass that value to next scenario and print that value for each datasetId. can someone please suggest how this can be implemented

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `before` section

```
package load

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class TransferTimeSimulation extends Simulation {

  var beforeScn1Start: Long = 0L

  before {
    println("Simulation is about to start!")
    beforeScn1Start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  }

  after {
    println("Simulation is finished!")
  }

  val scn1 = scenario("Scenario 1").exec(
    http("get google")
      .get("http://google.com")
      .check(status.is(200))
  )

  val scn2 = scenario("Scenario 2")
    .exec { session =>
      println("beforeScn1Start = " + beforeScn1Start)
      session
    }

  setUp(
    scn1.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
      .andThen(scn2.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))
  )
    .protocols(http)
    .maxDuration(10)
    .assertions(
      forAll.failedRequests.count.is(0),
    )
  
}
```

For more flexibilty you may also consider using lazy val initialization
https://www.baeldung.com/scala/lazy-val

Comment: how to implement this if I need to print current timestamp value before 2nd scenario and that too I need to do this during each iteration in the list for each value.